# как избежать вызова removeEventListener для каждого обработчика и сделать для всех сразу?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как избежать remo для каждого обработчика и сделать для всех сразу?

```
    componentWillUnmount() {
   renderer.domElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', 
   this.onMouseMoveObj, false);
   renderer.domElement.removeEventListener('mousedown', 
   this.onMouseDownObj, false);
renderer.domElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUpObj, false);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте данный способ:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    var oldElem = renderer.domElement;
    var newElem = oldElem.cloneNode(true);
    oldElem.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, oldElem);
}
```

Единственное но, этот способ очистит всех слушателей еще и в дочерних элементах для renderer.domElement

Answer (score 0):

Первое что бросается в глаза, это зачем вам Event listener'ы?

Чем стандартные synthetic events не устраивают?

Они сами добавятся когда компонент вмонтирован и сами удалятся, когда размонтирован.

Comment: а как мне в данном случае их использовать?